# how do we know that a file is read protected?

Tags: java, windows, file

In Java on Windows, how do we know that a file or folder is read-protected?

I try with  canRead() et setReadable() :

```
String pathFile = "D:/Folder";
File f = new File(pathFile);
System.out.println("Is Protected => " + f.setReadable(true)==true);
```

but it not solve my problem

Thank you

Comment: can you clarify as to how canRead() did not solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

canWrite method is true if and only if the file system actually contains a file denoted by this abstract pathname and the application is allowed to write to the file; false otherwise.

```
File lFile = new File("Sample.txt")
lFile.canWrite();
```

Comment: I'm talking about canRead() for file or folder is read-protected

Comment: For a File You May Use Like This
`File lFile = new File("d:\\test2.txt");
        if (lFile.exists()) {
            System.out.println("is ReadOnly = " + !lFile.canWrite());`
        }

Comment: if a file is allowed to write means it is not readonly..
if it not allowed to write means readonly...

simply Reverse Logic....

Comment: @prabhuprabhakaran if you cannot write to a file, that doesn't tell anything about the fact if you can read it or not

Comment: @eis ya, i think you are saying on a unix file system, i.e, rwx modes.

but in windows only readonly and non readonly.. 
At Default your always allowed to read a doc..

Comment: @prabhuprabhakaran um no. Windows has file permission system too. Try right clicking any file, go to properties -> security and check out read permissions on the lower panel (Windows 7).